# Removing CSS Elements Applied to theme header by Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

Does anyone know where in the Woocommerce plugin CSS is getting applied directly into the theme header? I have some CSS being placed directly into the header (not a CSS file being called, just the CSS code), and I need to either remove or edit only PART of it. Not the whole thing.

Comment: I am not familiar with Woocommerce but I will try to help anyway. If you know the properties that you want to remove or edit, you can just set it inside the tag, as you said that you've done, and it should override this CSS effects that you no longer want. Sorry if this is not the case or if I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. THe CSS properties that Woocommerce is putting in is overwriting any custom CSS.